# Really confused about sql injection

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-injection

Got this detail page about bug that might lead to sql injection

URL encoded GET input classid was set to 1 AND 3*2*1=6 AND 608=608

Tests performed:

- 1*1*1*1 => TRUE
- 1*608*603*0 => FALSE
- 11*5*2*999 => FALSE
- 1*1*1 => TRUE
- 1*1*1*1*1*1 => TRUE
- 11*1*1*0*1*1*608 => FALSE
- 1 AND 5*4=20 AND 608=608 => TRUE
- 1 AND 5*4=21 AND 608=608 => FALSE ... (line truncated)

And this is the source code that might cause the matter:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["classid"]))
{
    string tSql = @" SELECT  [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM  dbo.Web_Award WHERE ClassID={0} ";

    DataTable data = DbSession.Default.FromSql(string.Format(tSql, Request.QueryString["classid"])).ToDataTable();

    if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rptList.DataSource = data;
        rptList.DataBind();
    }
}
else
{
    string tSql = @" SELECT  [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM  dbo.Web_Award  ";

    DataTable data = DbSession.Default.FromSql(tSql).ToDataTable();

    if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rptList.DataSource = data;
        rptList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to deal with this...thanks a lot!

Now i have modifeid my code to

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["classid"]))
        {
            //string tSql = @" SELECT  [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM  dbo.Web_Award WHERE ClassID={0} ";
            string tSql = "SELECT [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM dbo.Web_Award WHERE ClassID = @ClassID";
            //DataTable data = DbSession.Default.FromSql(string.Format(tSql, Request.QueryString["classid"])).ToDataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;database=DaysQP");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(tSql, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClassId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
            command.Parameters["@ClassID"].Value = 1;
            using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var data = new DataTable();
                data.Load(dr);
                if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    rptList.DataSource = data;
                    rptList.DataBind();
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            string tSql = @" SELECT  [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM  dbo.Web_Award  ";
            DataTable data = DbSession.Default.FromSql(tSql).ToDataTable();
            if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rptList.DataSource = data;
                rptList.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

But the problem still exists..

Finally sovled the problem by using parameterized queries!

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["classid"]))
{   
    int number;
    bool result = Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["classid"], out number);

if (result == false)
{
    return;
}

//string tSql = @" SELECT  [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM  dbo.Web_Award WHERE ClassID={0} ";
string tSql = "SELECT [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM dbo.Web_Award WHERE ClassID = @ClassID";
 //DataTable data = DbSession.Default.FromSql(string.Format(tSql, Request.QueryString["classid"])).ToDataTable();

SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)DbSession.Default.CreateConnection();
//SqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;database=DaysQP");
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(tSql, connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClassId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
command.Parameters["@ClassID"].Value = number;
using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var data = new DataTable();
    data.Load(dr);
    if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rptList.DataSource = data;
        rptList.DataBind();
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

}

Comment: Use parameters. Don't concatenate SQL strings. It's that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential for injection would be here:

```
string tSql = @" SELECT  [Award_ID],[Award_Name],[Award_Info],[Award_Pic],[Award_Num],[Award_MoneyCost],[Award_MoneyGet],[Award_Type],[Award_AddDate],[Award_Hot],[Award_OnLineTime],[AwardProP],[PrizeSlidePic],[PrizeDetailPic],[PrizeBigSlidePic],[IsTop],[ClassID] FROM  dbo.Web_Award WHERE ClassID={0} ";
DataTable data = DbSession.Default.FromSql(string.Format(tSql, Request.QueryString["classid"])).ToDataTable();
```

You're expecting the query to return `Web_Award` table records whose `classId` matches `Request.QueryString["classid"]`

What happens if the value of `Request.QueryString["classid"]` is something like:

```
1 or 1=1
```

then the query becomes:

```
select award_id,..... from web_awards where classId=1 or 1=1
```

and you end up returning data that you never meant to.

This, in essence, is sql injection which you probably read up a bit more about. Using stored procedures or parameterized queries prevents this sort of attack.

Comment: I have modified my codes, but the problem still exists, would you please take a look at my new code..?

Comment: Give me some details ...what are you using to perform these tests? What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I have posted it as an answer